# looping infinitely through multiple arrays at the same time until a condition is met

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find **least common multiples** of the two numbers given `[3,5]` and return only the number that's divisible by all the number in the range of the two numbers... for example:

- The given array of two numbers --> `let arr = [3,5];`
- The first number Multiples should be as follow:

  `[3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,33,36,39,42,45,48,51,54,57,60];`
- The second number Multiples should be as follow:

  `[5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60];`
- The Least common multiples should be as follows:

  `[15,30,45,60];`

the only that is divisible by all the number in the range is `60`.

---

This is my approach to solve this problem but I want to know what's wrong with my code below (PLEASE EXPLAIN 'cause I'm tired of guessing):

```js
let arr = [3, 5];
let arrRange = []; // [3, 4, 5]

// creating a loop to create the range
for (var i = arr[0]; i <= arr[1]; i++) {
 arrRange.push(i);
}

let f = arr[0], s = arr[1], c = 0, result = 0, firstMultiples = [], secondMultiples = [], leastCommonMultiples = [];

// This function is made if the number least Common number is divisible by all the numbers in the "arrRange"
function isDivisible(num) {
  for(var i = 0; i < arrRange.length; i++) {
    if(num % arrRange[i] != 0) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}


while(true) {
  firstMultiples.push(f);
  secondMultiples.push(s);

  f = f + arr[0];
  s = s + arr[1];
  
  let vals = secondMultiples.values();
  for(let val of vals){
    if( firstMultiples.includes(val) ) {
      leastCommonMultiples.push(val);
 }
  }
 
  let cmlVals = leastCommonMultiples.values();
  for(let cmlVal of cmlVals){
    if(isDivisible(cmlVal)) {
    result += cmlVal;
    break;
 }
  }
  c++;
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: `the only that is divisible by all the number in the range is 60` explain this statement? 60 is divisible by `2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 15, 20 and 30` ... I don't see that "range" anywhere in the question ... nevermind, just saw what `range` is ... 3,4,5 ... and 3*4*5 == 60 ... so, not sure what your bistromathic code is attempting to do

Comment: by the way, you have no code to ever `break` out of the `while` loop - so, yes, your code will run until it runs out of memory

Comment: @JaromandaX This might help: https://www.mathsisfun.com/least-common-multiple.html

Comment: @JaromandaX why values can’t be pushed in the empty arrays I created? this really boogles my mind

Comment: who says they can't?

Comment: If you tried to console log any of them they will return nothing, but when I test the code blocks in the loop separately outside it works fine, so I’m sure that the loop has the problem somehow

Comment: your code loops infinitely, so how can you tell

Comment: I’m new to javascript, so what do you think the problem is in this code?

Comment: you have an infinite loop - this is always a problem in any language

Comment: I did the infinite loop on purpose because I don’t know for how long it should be running, and added break statement when the condition I specified is met, What am I doing wrong? I think it should keep looping and adding the values into their arrays ... unless there is something I don’t know about loops

Comment: no, you have no break for the while loop, you have an infinite while loop

Comment: The chrome console says secondMultiples.values is not a function, any thoughts?!

Comment: correct, an Array does not have a method called `values`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values

Comment: see [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/values#Browser_compatibility) on that page - are you using Edge or Safari?

Comment: may not be the most efficient algorithm - but given an array of values [this function](https://jsfiddle.net/gfqv49hb/) should give you the right answer

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, change the while-loop from `while (true) {/*code*/};` to 
   `while(isDivisible(cmlVal) == true) {/*code*/};` and remove the 
   `if(isDivisible(cmlVal)) {/*code*/ break;}`.